# How to remove first and last bracket from a matrix?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a matrix

```
var m= [ [ 1, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 1, 6 ] ];
```

I want output as

```
var m= [ 1, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 1, 6 ] ;
```

In JavaScript, what I am doing is sci lab sci code conversion to JavaScript code. I have tried this by converting the matrix to string but my program won't except the string output.

```
var m= "[ [ 1, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 1, 6 ] ]";
console.log(m.replace(/^\[([\s\S]*)]$/, "$1"));
```

but this gives a string output.

Comment: What is `m` supposed to be? Your wanted output isn't a valid object.

Comment: In JavaScript a matrix IS a multidimensional Array, so it is unclear what you want yo achieve?

Comment: In javascript [] represent an array. You have here array of arrays.

Comment: model.opar=list(new ScilabDouble(m[0],m[1]));

Comment: model.opar=list(new ScilabDouble(m[0],m[1]));   here i have to hard code it but want to automate it

Comment: Of course `String#replace` gives string output... So why do you use it if you don't want a string? The thing you say you want is not valid JavaScript. So this question is unclear as it stands. Please provide expected output in a JavaScript compliant syntax.

Comment: *but my program won't except the string output* What does your program accept?

Comment: the syntax model.opar=list(new ScilabDouble(m[0],m[1]));  accepts only arrays not matrix

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output isn't a valid type. You *could* destructure the matrix and assign each nested array to a separate variable, and that would look like this:

```js
const m = [[1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 6]];
const [ a, b, c, d ] = m;
console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

Is that something you could use?

Comment: this wont be happening dynamically like if it has 5 rows then this wont work

Comment: Well, apparently you can't use a string, and the output you _do_ want isn't valid, so you'll have to think of something else :/ Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: thats okk thanks a lott

Answer (score 0):

var myString = "[ [ 1, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 1, 6 ] ]";

var sillyString =myString.substring(1,myString .length – 1);

console.log(sillyString);